# Delete item from mysql database then go back to last page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a page where I list items ( in this case businesses) that are pulled from a mysql database with php.

```
<? 
    include('config.php');
    echo "<h3>Saved Businesses</h3>";
    echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none;'>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `saved_biz` WHERE user_id = '$id'") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); }
            $business_id = $row['business_id'];
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE id = '$business_id'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $business_name = $row['name'];
            }
        echo "<li>" . nl2br( $business_name);  
        echo "<a href=deletesavedbiz.php?id={$row['id']}>Delete</a></li>"; 
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</ul>"; 
?>
```

If the user decides to delete one of the businesses ( by clicking the "Delete" link ) he/she is then taken to deletesavedbiz.php and then, if successful, presented with a link to get back to the profile.php page that he/she was just on.

```
<? 
    include('config.php'); 
    $id = (int) $_GET['id']; 
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `saved_biz` WHERE `id` = '$id' ") ; 
    echo (mysql_affected_rows()) ? "Row deleted.<br /> " : "Nothing deleted.<br /> "; 
?> 

<a href='profile.php'>Back To Listing</a>
```

Now, what I want to do is have the php delete and then do like a php header redirect to profile.php without ever making the user click a link back. How can I accomplish this? Also, I'm fine with having the answer being javascript if it's not possible or not very clean in PHP.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do redirect in case your query returned `TRUE`.

```
function redirect($page = 'profile.php'){
 header("Location: $page");
 exit;
}


function your_query(){
    include('config.php');
    $id = (int) $_GET['id']; 
    //returns TRUE on success, FALSE otherwise
    return mysql_query("DELETE FROM `saved_biz` WHERE `id` = '$id' ") ; 
}


if ( your_query() ){
  redirerct();
} else {
  redirect('some_error_page.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: profile.php");
```

Put that at the bottom of your script that deletes the record.